# What are ways to get mutual friends in a (1, 2) (2, 1) friendship scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, relational-division

I'm developing a website wherein when a person adds another person as a friend, 2 entries are created. Let's say `uid 1` adds `uid 2` as a friend, the following rows are created in MySQL.

```
activity_id   uid1 uid2
     1         1     2
     2         2     1
```

`uid 2` becomes friends with `uid 3`:

```
activity_id   uid1 uid2
     1         1     2
     2         2     1
     3         2     3
     4         3     2
```

What are the ways to get the mutual friends between `uid 1` and `uid 2`? I'm using php and MySQL with no PDO experience (for now).

**[EDIT]**
Okay, so I decided to organize/normalize the tables. The relationship only generates 1 row now. which makes the table:

```
activity_id   uid1 uid2
     1         1     2
     2         2     3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the table format from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667589/getting-a-list-of-friends-names-from-mysql/9667821#9667821), this should do what you want;

```
SELECT name FROM users u
JOIN friends f1
  ON u.uid = f1.uid OR u.uid = f1.fid
JOIN friends f2
  ON u.uid = f2.uid OR u.uid = f2.fid
WHERE (f1.uid=1 OR f1.fid=1) AND (f2.uid=3 OR f2.fid=3) 
  AND u.uid<>1 AND u.uid<>3;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec6f1/1).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have called your table 'friends'.

This query will find common friends for users 1 and 3.

```
SELECT a.uid2
  FROM friends a
    INNER JOIN friends b
       ON a.uid2 = b.uid2
  WHERE a.uid1 = 1
   AND b.uid1 = 3
```

Don't you think it might be a bit presumptuous to make 2 rows though?  Maybe uid 2 doesn't really like uid 1 ?  (OTY).

Comment: Thanks for the concern, I actually have another column that states if they both accepted the friendship.

Comment: So I did end up normalizing the table which now only generates 1 row for each relationship. How should I go about the query this time around (see edit above)?

Comment: I think Erwin Brandstetter has covered it.

Answer (score 2):

To find all common friends of `uid 1` and `uid 2`:

```
SELECT t1.uid2
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (uid2)
WHERE  t1.uid1 = 1
AND    t2.uid1 = 2;
```

There is one special case, though: this query does not show whether `1` & `2` are friends!

BTW, your design seems a bit redundant. It should work with just one entry per friendship. (This query would have to be adapted for that, though.)

Basically this is another case of **relational division**. There are many different ways to skin this cat. [Find quite under this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation) - including performance testing and more information.

---

#### Query for updated question

Now there is only 1 row per friendship - a user can pop up in either column:

```
SELECT uid
FROM (
    SELECT uid2 AS uid FROM tbl WHERE uid1 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT uid1        FROM tbl WHERE uid2 = 1
    ) u1
JOIN (
    SELECT uid2 AS uid FROM tbl WHERE uid1 = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT uid1        FROM tbl WHERE uid2 = 2
    ) u2 USING (uid)
```

Comment: I changed the way I handle the relationships. It now just generates 1 row of data. Which of the query should I adjust? Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSanchez: I added a new version for your new situation.

Comment: Thank you. I did however encountered a problem with the new situation. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667589/getting-a-list-of-friends-names-from-mysql

Comment: @MikeSanchez: Yup - similar problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT distinct(uid2) FROM `test` where uid1=$uid union select distinct(uid1) from test where uid2=$uid";
```