# Getting a list of friend's names from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have a table named friends;

```
    friends
id   uid   fid
1     1     2   (1 is a friend of 2 and vice versa)
2     1     3   (1 is a friend of 3 and vice versa)
3     4     1   (1 is a friend of 4 and vice versa)
4     5     1   (1 is a friend of 5 and vice versa)
```

And a corresponding table for users;

```
  users
uid  name
1    mike
2    john
3    karl
4    mary
5    tony
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
SELECT name FROM users LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.uid=users.uid WHERE friends.uid='1' OR friends.fid='1'
```

What should my query be to get all the names of mike's friends?

Comment: what is data type of uid in Db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it just fine with a single, easy to index, query;

```
SELECT name FROM users u
JOIN friends f 
  ON u.uid = f.uid OR u.uid = f.fid
WHERE (f.uid=1 OR f.fid=1) 
  AND u.uid<>1;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6213/4).

Comment: There were a lot of answers but this is the one I tried. Worked like a charm. Thanks, @Joachim. +1 for introducing sqlfiddle to me.

Comment: Would you be also able to help me out here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663607/what-are-ways-to-get-mutual-friends-in-a-1-2-2-1-friendship-scenario/9664094#9664094

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
SELECT name from friends LEFT JOIN users on users.uid=friends.fid where friends.uid=1 UNION 
SELECT name from friends LEFT JOIN users on users.uid=friends.uid where friends.fid=1
```

This may look a little strange if anyone is ever friends with themselves.

Answer (score 2):

try one of these:

```
SELECT a.uid as UserID,
       a.`Name` as UserName,
      c.`Name as FriendsName
FROM users a LEFT JOIN friends b on a.uid = b.uid
    LEFT JOIN users c on b.fid = c.uid
```

OR

```
SELECT a.uid as UserID,
       a.`Name` as UserName,
      GROUP_CONCAT(c.`Name`) as FriendsList
FROM users a LEFT JOIN friends b on a.uid = b.uid
    LEFT JOIN users c on b.fid = c.uid
GROUP BY a.uid
```

Answer (score 1):

As in your [prequel question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664094/939860), you need to cover both foreign keys to the user table to get all his friends:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM  (
    SELECT uid FROM friends WHERE fid = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fid FROM friends WHERE uid = 1
    ) f
JOIN   users USING (uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch friends and users in your query and *I think* you'll get what you want.

In other words:

```
SELECT name FROM friends LEFT JOIN users ON friends.uid=users.uid WHERE friends.uid='1' OR friends.fid='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is right `SELECT name FROM users LEFT JOIN friends ON friends.uid=users.uid WHERE friends.uid=1 OR friends.fid=1`